# Java InputMismatchException error. How would I go about fixing this?

Tags: java, methods

It only appears when I enter 10 or more numbers that are 3's and 7's. It is coming from this method below, I tested it without this method. Here is the code

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer...");
    int num = input.nextInt();

    // Outputs
    System.out.println("Number of digits in number is " + numberDigits(num));
    System.out.println("Number begins with " + firstNum(num));
    System.out.println("Number ends with " + lastNum(num));
    System.out.println("Does number begin with 7? " + beginWith(num, 7));
    System.out.println("Does number begin with 3? " + beginWith(num, 3));
    System.out.println("Does number contain a 7? " + contains(num, 7));
    System.out.println("Does number contain a 3? " + contains(num, 3));
    System.out.println("Is the number divisible by 13? " + divTest(num, 13));
    System.out.println("Is the number divisible by 77? " + divTest(num, 77)); 
    System.out.println("How many times does 7 appear in the number? " + digitAppearances(num, 7));
    System.out.println("How many times does 3 appear in the number? " + digitAppearances(num, 3));

public static int digitAppearances(int num, int x) {

    // Check if num is 0
  if (num <= 0 ) {
    return 0;
  }

// Count number of times x appears
else if (num % 10 == x) {
    return 1 + digitAppearances(num / 10, x);
}
else {
    return digitAppearances(num / 10, x);
}
}
```

Comment: *That* code cannot throw `InputMismatchException`

Comment: An `InputMismatchException` is thrown by a `Scanner`, but I don't see one here.  Please post the code that actually throws that exception.

Comment: My apologies, it is there now.

Answer (score 1):

The `Scanner` is attempting to read an `int` with [the `nextInt` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--).

> An invocation of this method of the form `nextInt()` behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation `nextInt(radix)`, where `radix` is the default radix of this scanner.

- nextInt(radix):

> **Throws:**
>
> `InputMismatchException` - if the next token does not match the *Integer* regular expression, or is out of range

If you enter a value larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (about 2.1 billion, 10 digits), then you will get an `InputMismatchException`.

If you want to enter up to 19 digits, use `nextLong`.

If you want to enter an arbitrary number of digits, just call `next`, get the string, and validate that it only contains digits.  You'll need to convert the character digits to a numeric type before further processing.